# ElasticSearch regex return no result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query using `match` type and it returns results.

```
POST /kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "customer_first_name": "Mary"
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use `regex` type, it return no result.

```
POST /kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
    "query": {
        "regexp": {
            "customer_first_name": "M[a-z]ry"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the mapping type of `customer_first_name`?

Comment: "customer_first_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `customer_first_name` is analyzed, you need to do it like this (see the lowercase `m`):

```
POST /kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
    "query": {
        "regexp": {
            "customer_first_name": "m[a-z]ry"
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can also use the `keyword` sub-field in order to achieve what you want:

```
POST /kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
    "query": {
        "regexp": {
            "customer_first_name.keyword": "M[a-z]ry"
        }
    }
}
```